# Mysql DB Table Rows Disappearing

Tags: mysql

A really weird (for me) problem is occurring lately. In an application that accepts user submitted data the following occurs at random:

**Rows from the Database Table where the user submitted data is stored are `disappearing`.**

**Please note** that there is NO DELETE, DROP, TRUNCATE or other SQL statement issued on the database table except from the INSERT statement.

Could this be a bug of Mysql? Did some research on mysql.com (forums, bugs, etc) and found 2 similar cases but without getting a solid answer (just suggestions).

**Some info you might find useful:**
Storage Engine: InnoDB
User Submitted Data sanitized and checked for SQL Injection attempts

Appreciate any suggestions, info.

regards,

Comment: You'll probably get better answers over on servrfault; I've voted to move the question there.

Comment: Probably also worth saying what `CHECK TABLE` says (see my updated answer).

Comment: Hi, did you solve it? We've had the same issue and we can't diagnose the cause

Answer (score 3):

Here's 3 possibilities:

1. The data never got to the database in the first place. Something happened elsewhere so the data disappeared. Maybe intermitten network issues, overloaded server, application bug.
2. A database transaction was not commited, and got rolled back. Maybe a bug in your application code, maybe some invalid data screwd things up, maybe a concurrency exception occured etc.
3. A bug in mysql.

I'd look at 1. and 2. first.

Comment: Very, very good points 1 & 2. I think there are probably four or five other bullet items between numbers 2 and 3. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A table on which you only ever `insert` (and presumably `select`) and never `update` or `delete` should be *really* stable. Are you absolutely certain you're protecting thoroughly against [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attacks? Because those could (of course) delete rows and such if successful.

You haven't mentioned which table engine you're using (there are several), but it's well worth running whatever diagnostic tools there are for it on the table in question. For instance, on a MyISAM table, run [`myisamchk`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-table-maintenance.html). Or more generically (this works for several table types), use the [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/check-table.html) statement.

Have you had issues with the underlying storage? It may be worth checking for those.

Comment: you are right, i forgot to mention some details...
Storage Engine: InnoDB
User Submitted Data sanitized and checked for SQL Injection attempts

Answer (score 1):

Activating binlog and periodically monitoring DELETE queries can help to identify the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

One more case to fullfill the above. There could also be the case of client-side and server-side parts of application. Client-side initiated changes can be processed on the server side with additional code logics.

For example, in our case, local admin panel updated an order information with pay_date = NULL and php-website processed this table to clean-up overdue orders from this table. As php logics were developed by another programmer, it looked strange when orders update resulted in records to disappear after some time.

The same refers to crone operations, working on mysql database in a schedule.