# MYSQL Records Disappear (Java, c3p0)

Tags: java, mysql, c3p0, records

I have a JavaFX application with modules, interacting with MySQL database in different aspects. Dozens of modules communicate it successfully. But the module I test adds records to a table successfully (with INSERT IGNORE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE), then the same record is updated (UPDATE successful), and 15 minutes later this record disappears from database. id autoincrement doesn't roll back.

I noticed that records, that were inserted and never experienced my update query, don't disappear. Other old records in this table remain untouched. The problematic record is affected with this query:

```
UPDATE `order` 
SET 
`create_date` = '2014-03-20 00:00:00', 
`discount_coupon_id` = 0, 
`discount_percent_value` = 5, 
`comment` = '', 
`comment_length` = 0, 
`delivery_address` = 'Perm', 
`pay_date` = DEFAULT, 
`shipped_date` = DEFAULT, 
`delivery_date` = DEFAULT 
WHERE id = 407
```

After this query was executed, I've closed application and exited IDE, checked that record 407 is present and is updated (in HeidiSQL DB Editor). 15 minutes later I've checked for records' state and saw record 407 disappeared.

Details on table updated:

```
    CREATE TABLE `order` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `create_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `discount_coupon_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `discount_percent_value` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `comment_length` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `delivery_address` CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `pay_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `shipped_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `delivery_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=408;
```

I use c3p0 connection manager with default setup. Query is called like this:

```
try (
    Connection c = m.cpdsSayt.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();) {
  stmt.executeUpdate(SQL);
}
```

I've studied similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362570/mysql-db-table-rows-disappearing), but found no clue to my case, as I use no PROCEDURE, ROLLBACK or TRANSACTION. Though it looks like something is corrupted or unfinished from mysql's point of view and it throws out suspicious changes.

Application is cleint side and database is connected remotely, based on Hetzner virtual server.

Comment: Tried c3p0 parameter autoCommitOnClose(true) - unsuccessfully.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the same error without using your application: 1) open table in db editor, 2) execute the same query as in application, 3) close the table, wait for the period you tell the record disappears, 4) check the table contents; is the record there?

Comment: Yes, this happens in Editor as well. And it made us check server operations. I missed a detail in description and in my mind, that admin panel for the site is local and site is server-side application. Both were written by different programmers, so I didn't know that server-side application cleans up old orders when their create date and pay date differ much. Now it's clear. Anyway, the benefit is that you should better check for server side actions - application itself or crone operations.